# Simplify the expression using trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Simplify: $$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}$$

This looks to be similar to the Pythagorean identities: $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$.  However, I am not certain about how to approach this.  I'm thinking that I am going to have to rearrange on of the equations or split them up using the cos and sin theorems.  If someone could help me with this, it'd be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}$:

Given the Pythagorean identity, $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, rearrange the equation to say $\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)$. Replace the denominator with this to receive:

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \tan(x).$

Comment: Thanks very much, this was very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
\dfrac{\sin x \cos x}{1-\sin^2 x}= \dfrac{\sin x \cos x}{\cos^2 x}
$$